# Issues with using CollectionViewSource for grouping on a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, grouping

I have been trying to group data within my datagrid for a while now with no luck. In my ViewModel the properties:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<CompetitorModel> Competitors { get; } = 
            new ObservableCollection<CompetitorModel>();

public CollectionViewSource CompetitorsCollectionView { get; } =
            new CollectionViewSource();
```

And in my constructor:

```cs
CompetitorsCollectionView.Source = Competitors;

CompetitorsCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(
                new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(CompetitorModel.Qualification)));
```

Finally, my datagrid in my xaml:

```xml
<Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <!-- Datagrid Competition -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="Datagrid_Competition"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CompetitorsCollectionView}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Grid.Row="3"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
            IsReadOnly="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
            CanUserResizeRows="False"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            CanUserDeleteRows="True"
            CanUserAddRows="False">
        <!-- Grouping Style -->
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <!-- Column Information -->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Place"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Place}"
                    Width="45"
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Username}"
                    Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VIStart"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=VIStart}"
                    Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VIEnd"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=VIEnd}"
                    Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VIs"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=VIs}"
                    Width="Auto"
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=TimeFormated}"
                    Width="Auto"
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rerecords"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Rerecords}"
                    Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="DQ"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=DQ}"
                    Width="30"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DQReason"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=DQReasons}"
                    Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I have tried a variaty of things from using `ListCollectionView`s, which did work, but offer no ability to sort or useful down the road. That being said, this is what my tool looks lick with a `ListCollectionView` instead of a `CollectionViewSource`:
[image]

If anyone could point out where I have gone wrong, I would be very appreciative, as I cannot for the life of me solve this. Currently, none of the other posts I can find have solved my problem.

Edit: I don't know if it is important in solving the issue, but in my `App.xaml`, I have the following style defined for my datagrid groupings:

```xml
<!-- Datagrid Grouping Style -->
<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander x:Name="expander"
                            IsExpanded="True"
                            Background="DarkGray"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                            BorderThickness="1.75"
                            Margin="0,5">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Refer the example in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control

Comment: @TheLastStark I tried using this as a reference, but for some reason I cannot get it working. I don't think I understand it, so It's only making it harder to solve

Comment: I see, can you please show the CompetitorModel class as well

Comment: @TheLastStark [Sure, here is the recent on github](https://github.com/TimeTravelPenguin/TASCompAssistant/blob/master/Models/CompetitorModel.cs). But there isn't really anything in here that should be causing the issue

Comment: hmm.. weird, couldn't find anything, so when using a `ListCollectionView` it works fine?

Comment: Yeah, however that object doesn't have sorting options which I really need down the line, so I'm pretty sure I need to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work, but I would like to know if there's another way as well.

I created a `CompetitorCollection` property of `ICollectionView`, and bound it to the `DataGrid ItemsSource`

```
private ICollectionView _competitors;

public ICollectionView CompetitorCollection
 {
  get { return _competitors; }
 }
```

In the constructor

```
 _competitors = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Competitors);
_competitors.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(CompetitorModel.Qualification)));
```

Bind `CompetitorCollection` as the `DataGrid` Item Source.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Datagrid_Competition"
 ItemsSource="{Binding CompetitorCollection}"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 Grid.Column="2"
 Grid.Row="3"
 HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
 VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
 IsReadOnly="False"
 CanUserReorderColumns="False"
 CanUserResizeRows="False"
 CanUserResizeColumns="True"
 CanUserDeleteRows="True"
 CanUserAddRows="False">
```

**Alternative Method**

Create the `CollectionViewSource` inside the `Windows.Resource`

```
<Window.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DQ" Source="{Binding Path=Competitors}">
          <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
              <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Qualification"/>
          </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then in the `DataGrid` add the `CollectionView` we just created as the `ItemSource`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Datagrid_Competition"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DQ}}"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 Grid.Column="2"
 Grid.Row="3"
 HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
 VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
 IsReadOnly="False"
 CanUserReorderColumns="False"
 CanUserResizeRows="False"
 CanUserResizeColumns="True"
 CanUserDeleteRows="True"
 CanUserAddRows="False">
```

Then in the ViewModel only `Competitors` (which is of type `ObservableCollection<CompetitorModel>`) has to be present.

Comment: Amazing! That has done the trick. I hope it fills my purpose down the road. It should, so I am going to mark this as the solution! Thanks a million

Comment: Great!, you can also set the `CollectionViewSource` from the XAML and bind it to the source as well, I will add that to the solution later if you want.

Comment: Any and all solutions would be sweet